# Why does argc returns 2 when only 1 argument was passed?

Tags: c++, startup, argv, argc

I wrote this simple code to understand how the argument system works. I dragged a textfile to the .exe file, and get 2 as output instead of 1 as i expected.
Why 2? Is Arg 1 the .exe itself? How can i find out the filenames of the arguments?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    const int max = 100000;

    if (argc > 0)
    {
        cout<< argc <<endl;
    }

    cin.get(); cin.get();

  return 0;
}
```

And an additional question. Where can i inform on how to access each argument and use the informations. My goal is to open all files passed as arguments to the .exe.

---

This is not a duplicate question, i asked why 2 is returned when you pass 1 argument. The question in the Link is another...

Comment: The program always receives at least 1 argument, which is the program's name.

Comment: Why didn't you output the values of `argv`?  That would have answered your own question.

Comment: Because i did not knew that the values are stored here.
As you can read in my question: "How can i find out the filenames of the arguments?"

Comment: The argument may _be_ a filename, if that's what you pass in - but it's still just an argument. Print it like any other variable. You don't need to "find the filename" of a variable to see what's in there.

Comment: Why did this Question get so many down-votes? The only "fault" I see, is the question being very basic. But it explains what the inquirer has tried so far and even provides even a minimal example.

Comment: i also don't understand the downvotes,  there is not even feedback so i can learn what i can improve in my next question. Maybe some trolls are on this site.

Comment: @EdwardBlack Maybe the "research effort" was not enough.  If you know what `argc` is, but wasn't in the least bit curious as to what the `argv` sitting right next to it means, maybe those downvotes are warranted.

Comment: Lol, marked as duplicate even when i explained why it is no duplicate.

Comment: The answer on the other question explains what `argc` and `argv` are, and that : "virtually all implementations will prepend the name of the program to the array". It is a duplicate because you can find answers to all your questions there, and there is no need for so many answers repeating the same thing.

Comment: thats like saying "Read this C++ Book, all is explained there"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`argv[0]` is normally the name of the program being run, and is counted in `argc`.  If `argc >= 2`, the first of your text-file names should be in `argv[1]`.  You can simply loop over them...

```
for (size_t i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    if (std::ifstream infile(argv[i]))
        ...use infile...
    else
        std::cerr << "ERROR - unable to open " << argv[i] << '\n';
```

For more complex requirements, you may want to use [`getopt()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) et al if your system provides it, or the [boost library equivalents](http://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.boost.org%2Fdoc%2Flibs%2F1_55_0%2Fdoc%2Fhtml%2Fprogram_options.html&ei=aBCRVbC4H8KRuASKgbvQCg&usg=AFQjCNG82GiEhsBNHpALyvieuM3Qa73O1A).

Comment: Thx, this also answers my question on how to output the filename of the argument.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C++ Standard (3.6.1 Main function)

> 3. ...If argc is nonzero these arguments shall be supplied in argv[0]
>      through argv[argc-1] as pointers to the initial characters of
>      null-terminated multibyte strings (ntmbs s) (17.5.2.1.4.2) and **argv[0]
>      shall be the pointer to the initial character of a ntmbs that
>      represents the name used to invoke the program or ""**.

To output all arguments you can use various approaches as for example

```
for ( char **s = argv; *s; ++s ) std::cout << *s << std::endl;

for ( int i = 0; i < argc; i++ ) std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;


#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
//...
std::copy( argv, argv + argc, std::ostream_iterator<char *>( std::cout, "\n" ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

first argument for main is always name of execution file(means .exe file name)
that is why the value of argc is 2 ( 1 for program name and other for your .txt file)
you can check it by printing argv[0]